# Pythonic way to check generator values using its own elements

Tags: python, closures, generator

Say I'm reading in a file line by line, and want ensure that a certain character (e.g., a delimiter in tabular data) appears the same number of times in each line, based on its count in the first line of the file. The best I could come up with is this approach using a second generator, but I do not feel that this obeys 'there should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it'. Would using closures conform to this maxim, or is there some other obvious way that I'm failing to see?

```
def check_line(char='|'):
    while True:
        line_count = line.count(char)
        if i == 0:
           correct_count = line_count
        if line_count != correct_count:
           print """Line %d contains %d %s, should have %d""" % (
                 i, line_count, char, correct_count)
        yield None

with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
     checker = check_line()
     for i, line in enumerate(f):
         checker.next()
         ### do more things with line
```

I'm trying to abstract from my general problem a bit since I'm most curious about the idiomatic implementation, rather than solving this specific issue with files/delimiters.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to read it in as CSV and check that the right number of elements were in each line?

Comment: Sure, but that's why I'm trying to phrase this question abstractly rather than by specifically referencing CSVs (for one thing, there are other issues with the files that prohibit the use of standard CSV readers. Moreover, I'm most curious about the idiomatic solution to this particular problem as defined).

Comment: There is no *"correct implementation"*, just what does or doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: I'll edit it to reflect what I'm after, thanks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe there may not be a single "correct implementation" but I think making a generator rely on using global variables defined as the iteration variables in a for loop is probably not a very good route to take...

Comment: Your code wont run like this (notice that `line` is undefined in `check_line`). A more gerneric solution would be to wrap an arbitrary generator and return a new one. This is different from your current erroneous solution, that you don't have to do anything more as a user. You would still be working with a single generator and not two you couple.

Comment: actually @SebastianHoffmann `line` and `i` are both global variables defined in the for loop, this code runs fine if you fix the typo of `f` vs `file`.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Sorry I didn't expected code on SO to be understood as "runs in global scope".

Comment: It is meant to be run in the global scope, although that hackyness is sort of what I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of globals, pass the read lines into your generator:

```
def check_line(char='|'):
    correct_count = None

    while True:
        line = yield None
        line_count = line.count(char)
        if not correct_count:
           correct_count = line_count

        if line_count != correct_count:
           print """Line %d contains %d %s, should have %d""" % (
                 i, line_count, char, correct_count)

with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
     checker = check_line()
     for i, line in enumerate(f):
         checker.next(line)
```

---

A better solution would be to completely wrap a generator:

```
def check_line(gen, char='|'):
    correct_count = None
    injected = None

    while True:
        i, line = gen.next(injected)
        line_count = line.count(char)

        if not correct_count:
           correct_count = line_count

        if line_count != correct_count:
           print """Line %d contains %d %s, should have %d""" % (
                 i, line_count, char, correct_count)

        injected = yield i, line

with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
     checker = check_line(enumerate(f))
     for i, line in checker:
         print line
```

Comment: What's the `injected` for? It seems to work fine without it.

Comment: @HoHo It's to forward any values passed into your wrapping generator to the underlying generator. It's not required in this case but in there for correctness. Notice that this function works with any generator (as long as it yields 2-tuples).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think closures or generators are necessary. If it can be done with just a simple function definition, why should it use anything more complicated? Maybe I'm not understanding what you want well enough, but what I'd do is:

```
def check_lines(_file, delimiter):
    correct_count = _file.readline().count(delimiter)
    for line_number, line in enumerate(_file, start=2): #lets say the first line is line 1, then the first line in this for loop will be line 2
        line_count = line.count(delimiter)
        if line_count != correct_count:
            format_args = (line_number, line_count, delimiter, correct_count)
            print("""Line {} contains {} {}, should have {}""".format(*format_args))

with open(__file__, 'r') as _file:
    check_lines(_file, '(')
```

I don't know what the body your function is supposed to actually do. It can return or yield whatever information you need it to, instead of printing to stdout.

Comment: I'd like to do other things in my `for` loop outside of checking, so placing it in the function doesn't quite fix things. I guess my question is about how to create persistent variables in a loop that are created in another function, without relying on globals?

Comment: It's not clear in your question that was a requirement. Can you post exactly what you need solved instead of something just sort of related to it? Otherwise we'll end up sitting here guessing solutions to the wrong problem.

Comment: @HoHo then add `yield line_number, line` to the end of the for loop and then just do `for i,line in check_lines(_file,'('): ...`

Comment: the generator would then become basically a wrapper for `enumerate` that gives additional output.